# How to use lodash to count how many tags objects there are in this container?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

In the array of objects below there are 3 tags, how would you use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) to retrieve just the tag objects?

```
container = [Object, Object];

// container:
[
    0: Object {
        tags: [
            0: {
                term: "tag_name_1",
                term_id: 1111
            },
            0: {
                term: "tag_name_2",
                term_id: 2222
            }
        ],
        ticker: {
            name: "ticker1"
        }
    },
    1: Object {
        tags: [
            0: {
                term: "tag_name_3",
                term_id: 3333
            }
        ],
        ticker: {
            name: "ticker2"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `pluck`'em & flatten:

```js
var container = [
    {
        tags: [
            {
                term: "tag_name_1",
                term_id: 1111
            },
            {
                term: "tag_name_2",
                term_id: 2222
            }
        ],
        ticker: {
            name: "ticker1"
        }
    },
    {
        tags: [
            {
                term: "tag_name_3",
                term_id: 3333
            }
        ],
        ticker: {
            name: "ticker2"
        }
    }
];

var p = _(container).pluck('tags').flattenDeep();

alert(JSON.stringify(p, null, ' '));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hmm is there a way to split the tags completely out? The reason I ask is I need to count the tags, but right now as it, the length of the `p` array will be 2 instead of 3.

Comment: see revision (flattenDeep)

Comment: Ah yeah just did, had to run `_flatten` after `_pluck` :)

Comment: I don't see the advantage of using `flattenDeep()` over `flatten()`.

Comment: @AdamBoduch - original version had no flatten, then the request was "tuned" to require a flat array. I make no assumptions regarding the complete data structure and assume I only see a sample of the data. It's "safer" to use flattenDeep if there is no knowledge of the complete data and the end results should always be flat.